# MSAccess subform using BIGINT (Large Number)

Tags: sql, ms-access, bigint

I'm getting the error when trying to link a form and a subform with ID beeing type BIGINT

> "One of your parameter is invalid"

Form is done using record like :

```
ID : bigint
Value A : int
```

Subform is done using record like :

```
ID : bigint
Value B : int
```

The ID type cannot be change to INT as they come from SQL linked table created by an external software

```
Linked Master Field : ID
Linked Child Field : ID
```

Comment: If your BigInt values are smaller than Long, try using `CLng(ID)`.

Comment: I've created a query that add a column like `ID2 : CLng(ID)` and then use this column to linked the form - subform it does seem to work ! Thanks Gustav

Comment: Great! Then please mark as answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Gustav proposed :

Creating a value `ID2: CLng(ID)` and use this value to link the form solved the issue